# Rails ActiveJob Dry Runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rails-activejob

I need to enable some "dry-run" option for some of my ActiveJobs.

For my specific case, I need to run "chase" jobs for users that have not replied to a message after x days (amongst other conditions)

I already have feature tests that should take care of the majority of cases, but I'd like to try and detect potential corner-cases I'd have forgotten, by launching a dry run on my production database, and maybe sample the results.

I am wondering how to best do that, and the solution I came up with involves modifying every perform() method to add an option hash (where I would pass `dry_run: true` that skips the execution).

I am also wondering how to best make the results of the dry-run available. Ideally someone from the Rails web interface should be able to see the logs or whatever output was produced by the job. Any idea that would be better than parsing a logfile ? :S

Comment: How about: start a transaction, run the job inside the transaction, perform some methods to see what changes have you produced and then rollback the transaction. Needless to say I would do this on a production database clone :)

Comment: Unfortunately I had to do this on my production database directly (for time reasons) and I managed to pull it off by adding some `dry_run_` prefixes to my models when I had to persist some fields (`dry_run_last_ "chase"_message_sent_at'), and then I clean the dry_run fields after the batch is complete.